How to add x5t header to JWT generated through Spring Authorization Server
I am creating an OAuth2 authorization server using Spring Authorization Server.
For generating JWT, I have configured the RSAKey. I have set the certificate's SHA-1 thumprint using RSAKey.Builder.x509CertThumbprint method. However, once I generate the token, the x5t header is not included.
If I set the SHA-256 thumbprint, then that is added in the generated JWT's header.
Also, the method RSAKey.Builder.x509CertThumbprint is marked deprecated. But I need to have the x5t header added. Is there any way I can add it?

RSAKey.Builder.x509CertThumbprint lets you add a SHA-1 thumbprint to the RSA key. The Nimbus library has deprecated the usage of SHA-1 hashes following an announcement from the Google about collisions.
See this issue for more information.
That being said, you can add a SHA-256 thumbprint to the builder using the x509CertSHA256Thumbprint() method.
Eg:
RSAKey.Builder(rsa_public_key)
    .privateKey(private_key)
    .x509CertSHA256Thumbprint(thumbprint)
    .keyID(key_id)
    .build();

This will add a x5t#S256 header to the JWT.
eg:
{
  "x5t#S256": "KJKNDKnksdiserwienw",
  "kid": "123412341234",
  "alg": "RS256"
}

EDIT:
More info on the x5t#S256 header can be found here.
